# How to create a new folder in a device with android?

Tags: java, android

i want to create new folder in the root of my device but i can't :(
how I want to go to the root of my device and creates a new folder, for example, my device has the letter G: / I want to create the file just there "G: / new folder" sorry for the poor drafting

Comment: Doesn't this work? `new File("/newFolder").mkdirs();`

Comment: I doubt that you can create a folder under root (of the linux file system). However, you can create a folder under the root of the SDcard, if you have declared the proper permission in your APP. Please clarify what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you can't just go to the root dir of your device and create it programmatically in your app, since the app is running as a separate user which doesn't have those privileges. Moreover, I doubt you can do it as a simple user manually on your phone, because you are not root either. (I am not even talking about hardcoding letter of the disk partition)

The main question here is I guess why you would need that folder. If it is for app purpose, then, you should look at this documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

It has pretty much all described starting from storage on your server ending with preference files.